# Mutual friends and connections with Instagram API in PHP

Tags: php, instagram-api

I am trying create a sort of graph where the nodes are the profile pictures of all my instagram follows and the edges connecting any two nodes will be a sort of connection specifying whether the users are following eachother. Will I need some sort of permission to access all my friends follows? 
How do I go about this?

Comment: Have you read the API doc?

Answer (score 0):

You have to get `follower_list` permission and then use API to get all followers and following:

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/follows?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN

https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/followed-by?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN
```

Get all the users using `pagination` and store in array, then do a compare and find matches.

(You can only access all users if you are in live mode, u will only be able to get your sandbox approved users in sandbox mode)